# Sails Js Request Entity too large error

Tags: javascript, sails.js, body-parser

I am making a request to a Sails Js app (v0.12) and I am getting a 413 (Request Entity too large) error.

I have been trying to increase the request limit in the bodyParser, But it does not seem to take effect.

Under `config/http.js`, I added a custom bodyParser function that uses `skipper` and increases the limit

```
bodyParser: (function() {
  var opts = { limit: '50mb' };
  var fn;

  // Default to built-in bodyParser:
  fn = require('skipper');
  return fn(opts);

}),
```

How can I properly increase the request limit in SailsJs?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. And in my case I found an issue in *Nginx* config. 
Maybe you have smth similar if you running Nginx or Apache.